# Using more than one MapperConfig in a DI Container

Tags: c#, automapper, profile

I would like to create two MapperConfigs, one mapping flattened objects and the other mapping nested objects and then use both MapperConfigs in one repository. Is this possible?

This is my MapperConfig and I provide both methods to the DI container.

```
internal static class MapperConfig
{
  internal static IMapper InitAutoMapper()
  {
      // Configuring AutoMapper
      var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
      {
          cfg.AddProfile(new BooksProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new AuthorProfile());
          
          cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
      });

      // Creating the Mapper Instance
      return config.CreateMapper();
  }
  
  internal static IMapper InitFlattenMapper()
  {
      // Configuring AutoMapper
      var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
      {
          cfg.AddProfile(new BooksFlattenProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new AuthorFlattenProfile());
          
          cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
      });

      // Creating the Mapper Instance
      return config.CreateMapper();
  }
}
```

I want to work with inheritance, so that with the ParentProfile the flattened mapping can be taken. In contrast, the ChildProfile can also be mapped with nesting.

```
internal class BookFlattenProfile : Profile
    {
        public BookFlattenProfile()
        {
            this.RecognizePrefixes("Bk");
            this.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("Bk");

            this.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Author, act => act.Ignore())
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
internal class BookProfile : BookFlattenProfile
    {
        public BookProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Author, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Author))
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to use it in my Repository, but it use only one MapperConfig.
I would like to use either two different mappers or the mapper can switch between two provided mapperconfigs.

```
public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
    {
        private IContextFactory _context;
        private IMapper _mapper;
        private IMapper _flatMapper;

        public BookRepository(IContextFactory context, IMapper mapper, IMapper flatMapper))
        {
            this._context = context;
            this._mapper = mapper;
            this._flatMapper = flatMapper;
        }
     }

     public async Task<List<BookDTO>> GetAllBooks()
        {
            using (var context = this._context.CreateContext())
            {
                return await context.Book.Take(2000).ProjectTo<BookDTO>(this._mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
                }
            }
        }

     public async Task<List<BookDTO>> GetBookWithAuthor(int id)
        {
            using (var context = this._context.CreateContext())
            {
                return await context.Book.Where(e => e.Id == id).ProjectTo<BookDTO>(this._flatMapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `MapperConfiguration` is expensive. I suggest that you use different DTOs instead. You can use mapping inheritance to reuse configuration if needed.